# CPython - Compile dails, PyDateTime_FromTimestamp not declared?

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7, v8, cpython

I'm writing a V8 add-on to convert javascript objects to python, and vice-versa. I'm able to convert all sorts of types, but `PyDateTime_FromTimestamp` (which is specified as existing in the cpython docs: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/datetime.html#c.PyDateTime_FromTimestamp) is apparently undefined, causing compilation to fail.

```
../src/py_object_wrapper.cc:189:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 
'PyDateTime_FromTimestamp'
        return PyDateTime_FromTimestamp(value->NumberValue());
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Needless to say, if I just download the latest Python 2.7 source and build it, I don't get this error, and if I then build the sample embedding app, I don't get this error, and when I look at the source, [`PyDateTime_FromTimestamp`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Include/datetime.h#l225) is there. So, you're obviously either configured wrong (e.g., using Python 2.6 headers against Python 2.7 code), doing something wrong in your code (maybe trying to `#include` individual headers instead of the combined header, and missing `datetime.h`), or doing something wrong in your build setup.

Comment: And without knowing anything at all about your setup, seeing any of your code, seeing how you're building, seeing the full build output, etc., there's no obvious way to help you debug the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't given us enough information to debug anything, I'm going to take a wild guess at the most likely problem.

Notice that at the top of the [documentation you linked to](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/datetime.html) it says:

> Various date and time objects are supplied by the `datetime` module. **Before using any of these functions, the header file `datetime.h` must be included in your source (note that this is not included by `Python.h`)**, and the macro `PyDateTime_IMPORT` must be invoked, usually as part of the module initialisation function. The macro puts a pointer to a C structure into a static variable, `PyDateTimeAPI`, that is used by the following macros.

If you just forgot the macro, this would compile but then crash at runtime, as `PyDateTimeAPI` will be NULL.

But if you forgot to `#include` the `datetime.h`, that would cause exactly what you're seeing.